# How to remove a line break from CSV output

Tags: python-3.x, csv, split

I am writing this code to separate information which will be uploaded to a database using the resulting CSV file from the code I wrote.  I have it so that if I receive a spreadsheet with First, Middle, and Last name all in the same column they can be split into three separated columns.  However my output file has some extra line breaks or returns or something which I just went through in the CSV and deleted manually to get the data uploaded for now.  How can I remove these within my code?  I have some ideas but none seem to work.  I tried using line.replace but I do not fully understand how that is supposed to work so it failed.

My code:

```
import csv

with open('c:\\users\\cmobley\\desktop\\split for crm check.csv', "r") as readfile:

name_split = []

for line in readfile:

    whitespace_split = line.split(" ")

    remove_returns = (line.replace('/n', "") for line in whitespace_split)

    name_split.append(remove_returns)

print (name_split)



with open ('c:\\users\cmobley\\desktop\\testblank.csv', 'w', newline = '\n')     as csvfile:

        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ',',
                            quotechar = '"', quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        writer.writerows(name_split)
```

Thanks for any help that can be provided!  I am still trying to learn Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a forward-slash rather than a **backward**-slash needed for escape sequences.

Change to:

```
remove_returns = (line.replace('\n', "") for line in whitespace_split)
```